# Задача. Скачать файлы с сайтов которые находятся в файле txt

Tags: python

Задача:
На­пиши прог­рамму, которая про­ходит сай­ты по спис­ку, ска­чива­ет фай­лы robots.txt и sitemap.xml и сох­раня­ет на диск. В слу­чае если файл не най­ден, выводит­ся сооб­щение об этом.

Проблема:
Не могу разобраться как правильно считывать robots.txt вместе с sitemap.xml и как вывести сообщение о том что файл не найден.
В файле site_base.txt сайты сохранены в формате:

```
https://xakep.ru
https://habr.ru
https://vc.ru
...
```

Вот наброски:

```
import requests
import shutil
import os
import urllib
with open('site_base.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() + '/robots.txt'
        print(line)
        dirname, filename = os.path.split(line)
        r = requests.get(line, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(urllib.parse.urlsplit(line).netloc + ".txt", 'wb') as j:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, j)
      # elif r.status_code != 200:
      #     print('На сайте' + line + 'файл robots.txt не найден!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
...

...
for line in f:
    line = line + '/robots.txt'
    print(line)
    dirname, filename = os.path.split(line)
    try:
        r = requests.get(line, stream=True)
    except ConnectionError:
        print('Error')
        continue
...
```